# Add asp.net pages into sharepoint

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

How to add or open the asp.net pages from inside sharepoint?
I found many info on the web about that, but they all fail or they are not clear. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: COuld you be a little clearer please? How do you deploy your pages, are they custom (i.e. an application you want to run under Sharepoint), are they publishing pages etc. Not much to go with the information you provided....

Comment: Why is this down-voted??? This is a good question, with a good answer. He did his best in asking the question.

Comment: It is down-voted because it is a low-quality question, at least that is my guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to include an aspx page to call either using an AJAX include or to be able to use the MOSS Object Model without having to add references etc?

if so then the following steps are necessary:

1. navigate to 12\layouts\
2. create a folder for the asp.net files
3. put the inline code files in
4. From sharepoint you can add a page viewer web part and reference it with the following url _Layouts//Filename.aspx

This technique will only work with inline code, if you wish to compile your code then you would create the site as normal and then add an application folder within the virtual directory of that particular site for example my site is called intranet:

1. navigate to c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\intranet
2. add your asp.net folder to this as a sub folder
3. in inetmgr right click the folder and create an application for it (use the same app pool as the sharepoint site)
4. ensure ALL DLLs from the sharepoint site bin folder exist within the apps bin folder or it will throw an error.

**However, I would only ever use these methods as proof of concept and would ultimately use web parts, custom features and workflows to carry out the same functions.**

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear, but if you want to customize look'n'feel of SharePoint page you should use [SharePoint Designer](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/FX100487631033.aspx?ofcresset=1).

In case you want to create some additional functionality from scratch the easiest way is to [create a custom web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452873.aspx) and then [add it to a SharePoint page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA011605831033.aspx).

Comment: Good answer, but I would deploy custom pages through a feature though (perhaps after creating them in SharePoint designer)

Comment: Yep, I could not agree more... but features are not something I would recommend for a novice user.

Comment: Dunno, seeing what an integral part it is of sharepoint, i'd say to go and try it out as soon as possible. Although i started out wacking DLL's in the GAC manually and then upload .aspx pages through sharepoint designer as well i have to admit :-D.

Comment: IMHO (and real experience) for newbie SharePoint developers WebParts+GAC is much better approach. When they learn how to master these they are ready to move on... A smart guy can deploy just a few web parts and (s)he is ready to move on to features and solutions... my 2 cents.